# does ubuntu or pulseaudio roll off (sub-)bass?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

A while back when i just started messing around with ubuntu I thought I noticed that the same audio files, when played back on ubuntu, had considerably less bass compared to windows. Gave up on trying to figure out what was going on because A/B-ing between two operating systems is hard and most things sounded "fine" to me anyway, but I did manage to rule out the possibility that windows was actually boosting bass.

So today i tried recording something with audacity through an external audio interface with the ability to cross-fade between the input and the audio from the DACs, and this revealed that the difference is huge. Also, it doesn't matter if i play back the audio from audacity or with any other media player I've tried so far. I'm certain the problem isn't in the AD converters because if that was the case I would have noticed this difference on windows a long time ago, and all posts I've been able to find on equalizers all ask for a "bass boost". This might make some movies sound more impressive by boosting somewhere between 100 and 200 hz or something, but that's a workaround, not a fix.

Kind of at a loss here, can anyone help?

I'm on stock ubuntu 16.04.1 with pulseaudio version 8.0. The audio interface is a TC-electronics desktop konnekt 6.

Comment: Could you please add your Ubuntu version and flavour?

Comment: OMG you did not ask about this, but — unless you have enrolled into Extended Security Maintenance support — your warranty is expiring just as we speak! You need to upgrade to a supported Ubuntu version like, in weeks, because security patches for your system stop coming. [Here is a pic](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/19515/1157519) about the release cycle and end of life.

Comment: Oh oops, lol. The only reason I'm even trying to record stuff on ubuntu is because I broke my windows installation and have been too lazy to fix it, but now I'm learning about pulseaudio. Funny how that works I guess.
Also, I know the old firewire interface makes this a very specific use-case, but I think it should be more generally applicable to interfaces that are kind of supported but don't fit a standard profile, no?

Comment: "the old firewire interface makes this a very specific use-case" — Well, it gets very relevant why this site [has a majority-supported policy](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/19510/1157519) for not dealing with questions about unsupported Ubuntu versions. The relevance of the problems and the usefulness of the answers erode very quickly at that point. "it should be more generally applicable to interfaces that are kind of supported but don't fit a standard profile" — possibly; hence my engagement, even though I couldn't reproduce the issue :)

Comment: Alright, I'll update and see if and how that changes the answer when I have time tomorrow.

Comment: "I'll update and see" "tomorrow" haha, good luck. Luckily you already have an account here so you can ask about all the troubleshooting ;) Oh heck, jokes aside, Ubuntu 16.04 still defaults to Unity desktop, while anything after defaults to Gnome 3 desktop. Honestly, better plan for backing up all your data then a fresh reinstall of the entire system; you'll be done 10x faster.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that, since my audio interface has more than one stereo output, pulseaudio thinks it's a 5.1/7.1 card or something of the sort.

This, apparently, can be fixed by un-commenting this line in `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf` (remove the leading semicolon and space from it):

```
; enable-lfe-remixing = no
```

This change brings my bass back to normal levels.

Comment: Would you want to add the full path to the daemon.conf file to your answer?

Comment: There might be a better, more generalized answer to that question, but on my system it's in the /etc/pulse/ directory and i can access the file with the right permissions by typing:

        sudo nano /etc/pulse/daemon.conf

Comment: On stock Ubuntu 20.04 with pulseaudio version 13.99.1, I do not see the line `; enable-lfe-remixing = no`. But the [`daemon.conf` docs for 20.04](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man5/pulse-daemon.conf.5.html) (one can switch versions on the page-top tab bar) indicate this parameter, so I assume if it's not in `daemon.conf` initially, it could be added then. With the value set to no, and without the semicolon, of course.

Comment: For users of pulseaudio v `14.x`, according to [the changelog](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pulseaudio/pulseaudio/-/blob/master/NEWS), "The enable-lfe-remixing option in daemon.conf was split into remixing-produce-lfe and remixing-consume-lfe". Looks like the new version [will even suggest](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pulseaudio/pulseaudio/-/blob/master/src/daemon/daemon-conf.c#L515-516) how to migrate to the new params.

Comment: In my use case just disabling remixing altogether by un-commenting `; enable-remixing = no`  (and disabling by changing yes to no if necessary) seems to have the same effect. I'm not entirely sure but I think this gets you into trouble when you try to play surround sound through a stereo output.